# How can I use the Apple SDK on the PC?

Tags: ipad

I have a need to build apps for an iPad but I do not have a Mac, is it possible to run the Apple SDK on a PC, through an emulator or some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build an officially sanctioned and Apple approved application, you need to build that application on Apple hardware.

No easy way around it.

Comment: And I would have thought that even for a non-sanctioned, non-Apple-approved application, you’ll have a much easier time of things in XCode, which only runs on Mac OS X, which only runs on Apple hardware.)

Comment: All we are REALLY trying to do at the moment is to put some shortcuts to files (KeyNote presentation, videos, etc) directly on the menu.  From what I've seen so far you have to develop an app that opens the app you want to the specified file.  Say what you want about Windows, but Microsoft is no where NEAR as proprietary and difficult to deal with as Apple.

Comment: @Mike C : you're so right, just look at their long history of  published whitepapers on the Word format. No sense of proprietary info there. ;)

Comment: I said nowhere near AS proprietary :).  You can read Word format on every OS, you don't need to buy a Microsoft PC.  We just sucked it up and bought an iMac.  So I have an iMac, and an iPad in my office.  I got Xcode downloaded and wrote a simple hello world.  Ran it on the simulator just fine, but so far it looks like in order to run the test app on my iPad I will have to pay $99 for a developers license..  at what point to I have do I get to stop jumping through hoops to do the simplest things??!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest version of virtualbox for windows and run mac os on it. See  http://www.sysprobs.com/install-mac-snow-leopard-1063-oracle-virtualbox-32-apple-intel-pc

A little clunky right now, but virtualbox is supposed to add more support for the display resolution and other integration features. Just make sure you make the virtual disk big enough > 20gb.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more details. Apple SDK is gcc-derived multilib toolchain compiled to run on Darwin like systems + Cocoa & friends (headers and compiled libraries). All these frameworks and binaries are multiarch MACH-O binaries which simply won't run on non-Darwin platforms. So this is not superficial restrictions, simply SDK will not run.